# How to keep the orientation of end effector during movement in ROS Gazebo simulation

Tags: control, robotic-arm, ros, gazebo, orientation

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, ROS NOETIC, Moveit to control a UR5 robotic arm in Gazebo simulation. I am trying to move a robot with a fixed orientation of its end-effector. The basic idea is to use the robotic arm to scan through a table surface, with the end-effector perpendicular to the surface all the time.

I would like to use python code to realise this function. I tried "PoseStamped", but it still cannot fix the orientation.

Can any expert give me some suggestions?